# Write Azure Data Factory Output Parameter to dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to write an output parameter to a dataset?

I have a meta data activity that stores the file name of an azure blob dataset and I would like write that value into another azure blob dataset as an additional column via a copy activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the output of the previous operation as an input to the next operation, you could probably go ahead in the following manner,

I am hoping that the attribute you are getting is the child Items, the values for this can be obtained in the next step using the following expression.

`@activity('Name_of_activity').output.childItems.`

This would return an `Array` of your subfolders.

The following link should help you with the expression in [ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions)